# Pass Context to another Activity

Tags: android, database, android-activity, helper, android-context

I am Having a DataBase Helper class which is not an activity. Here I want to show a Toast that require a context. How can I pass a context from Another Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Object of The Helper class from your Activity and pass 'this' as the context, say

```
    MyHelperclass helper=new MyHelperclass(this);
```

In the Helper class Get this Context via its constructor

```
Context context;
MyHelperClass(Context context){
this.context=context;
}
```

Now You can pass this context to the makeText() method of Toast class.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method like `setContext(Context context)` in your `DataBase Helper` class to pass your context from your activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the context if you do getApplicationContext(); from your activity and pass that to your DBHelper class.